# How to Copy Specific Data from 1 table to Another table using C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, copy

I am trying to copy specified data from table "sale" to another table "sale_temp", which is specified by "where inv_reff = @inv_reff". I am working on visual studio 2010 C# winform.
My code do nothing till i remove "where inv_reff = @inv_reff & its parameter".
my code

```
private void btn_srch_sale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int s;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter dat = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Pakrelible\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        //SqlCommand dat = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        dat.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sale_temp", con);
        dat.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        s = dat.Fill(dt);

        if (s >= 1)
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Please Complete Sale Invoice First...!!!", "Error");
            this.aca.Focus();
            return;
        }
        int x;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Pakrelible\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        ***SqlCommand copy = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sale where inv_reff = @inv_reff ");   \\ problem goes here***
        copy.Parameters.Add("@inv_reff", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = inv_sale.Text;
        conn.Open();
        copy.Connection = conn;


        SqlDataReader sale_copy = copy.ExecuteReader();

        sale_copy.Read();

        while (sale_copy.Read())
        {

            aca_sale.Text = sale_copy["aca"].ToString();
            acn_sale.Text = sale_copy["acn"].ToString();
            act_sale.Text = sale_copy["act"].ToString();
            tele_sale.Text = sale_copy["tele"].ToString();
            memo_sale.Text = sale_copy["memo"].ToString();
            memo2_sale.Text = sale_copy["memo2"].ToString();
            inv_sale.Text = sale_copy["inv_reff"].ToString();
            inv_date_sale.Text = sale_copy["inv_date"].ToString();
            mode_sale.Text = sale_copy["mode"].ToString();
            reff_sale.Text = sale_copy["reff"].ToString();
            employe_sale.Text = sale_copy["employe"].ToString();
            dis_sale.Text = sale_copy["dis"].ToString();



            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlConnection connn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Pakrelible\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into sale_temp (aca,acn,act,tele,memo,memo2,inv_reff,inv_date,mode,reff,brand,part_no,descrp,qty,unt_prc,total_prc,employe,dis )" + "values(@aca,@acn,@act,@tele,@memo,@memo2,@inv_reff,@inv_date,@mode,@reff,@brand,@part_no,@descrp,@qty,@unt_prc,@total_prc,@employe,@dis )", connn);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@aca", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["aca"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@acn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["acn"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@act", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["act"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@tele", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["tele"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@memo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["memo"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@memo2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["memo2"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@inv_reff", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["inv_reff"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@inv_date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["inv_date"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["mode"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@reff", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["reff"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@brand", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["brand"].ToString();
            //da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@brand", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["brand"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@part_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["part_no"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@descrp", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["descrp"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["qty"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@unt_prc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["unt_prc"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@total_prc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["total_prc"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@employe", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["employe"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@dis", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["dis"].ToString();
            //da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@amnt_wrd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["amnt_wrd"].ToString();


            connn.Open();
            x = da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (x >= 1)
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();


                SqlConnection connnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Pakrelible\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
                DataTable sdt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT brand,part_no,descrp,qty,unt_prc,total_prc FROM sale_temp ", connnn);
                sda.Fill(sdt);
                sale_grid.DataSource = sdt;
                connnn.Dispose();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Posting !", "Error");
                }
}
```

if i remove "where inv_reff = @inv_reff" then thees codes copy complete data from table.
can any guy help me, may be i am missing something or have another way ...!! Please help me through coding or told my mistake,Don't give me links..

Comment: But why would you remove `where inv_reff = @inv_reff`?

Comment: Because thees code dO nothing till i remove "where inv_reff = @inv_reff".

Comment: Then `inv_sale.Text` does not match any record.

Comment: Nop there is no Mistake i am sure.I change whole data to & tried all the thing that i can...

Comment: Wait. _Without_ the `where` _all_ records are fetched. _With_ the `where` _none_. It must be the `@inv_reff` parameter not getting a matching value. Leading or trailing spaces involved? Case sensitive?

Comment: nop there is no any space or anything else I am sure, their is Only NUMERIC VALUES.Ok leave it,Another Question i have reportViewer & wanna Specific data from table "sale" to print,How & What parameter I have to use for it.Like I enter inv_reff in text box then press search Button that load data from table to reportVeiwer.I already design it but don't know what parameter use behind search button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem and that is

```
"while (sale_copy.Read())" insteed of this only "(sale_copy.Read())"
```

Complete Codes

```
private void btn_srch_sale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int s;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter dat = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Pakrelible\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        //SqlCommand dat = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        dat.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sale_temp", con);
        dat.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        s = dat.Fill(dt);

        if (s >= 1)
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Please Complete Sale Invoice First...!!!", "Error");
            this.aca.Focus();
            return;
        }
        int x;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Pakrelible\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        ***SqlCommand copy = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sale where inv_reff = @inv_reff ");   \\ problem goes here***
        copy.Parameters.Add("@inv_reff", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = inv_sale.Text;
        conn.Open();
        copy.Connection = conn;


        SqlDataReader sale_copy = copy.ExecuteReader();

        while (sale_copy.Read())
        {

            aca_sale.Text = sale_copy["aca"].ToString();
            acn_sale.Text = sale_copy["acn"].ToString();
            act_sale.Text = sale_copy["act"].ToString();
            tele_sale.Text = sale_copy["tele"].ToString();
            memo_sale.Text = sale_copy["memo"].ToString();
            memo2_sale.Text = sale_copy["memo2"].ToString();
            inv_sale.Text = sale_copy["inv_reff"].ToString();
            inv_date_sale.Text = sale_copy["inv_date"].ToString();
            mode_sale.Text = sale_copy["mode"].ToString();
            reff_sale.Text = sale_copy["reff"].ToString();
            employe_sale.Text = sale_copy["employe"].ToString();
            dis_sale.Text = sale_copy["dis"].ToString();



            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlConnection connn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Pakrelible\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into sale_temp (aca,acn,act,tele,memo,memo2,inv_reff,inv_date,mode,reff,brand,part_no,descrp,qty,unt_prc,total_prc,employe,dis )" + "values(@aca,@acn,@act,@tele,@memo,@memo2,@inv_reff,@inv_date,@mode,@reff,@brand,@part_no,@descrp,@qty,@unt_prc,@total_prc,@employe,@dis )", connn);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@aca", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["aca"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@acn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["acn"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@act", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["act"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@tele", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["tele"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@memo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["memo"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@memo2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["memo2"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@inv_reff", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["inv_reff"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@inv_date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["inv_date"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["mode"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@reff", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["reff"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@brand", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["brand"].ToString();
            //da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@brand", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["brand"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@part_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["part_no"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@descrp", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["descrp"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["qty"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@unt_prc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["unt_prc"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@total_prc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["total_prc"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@employe", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["employe"].ToString();
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@dis", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["dis"].ToString();
            //da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@amnt_wrd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sale_copy["amnt_wrd"].ToString();


            connn.Open();
            x = da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (x >= 1)
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();


                SqlConnection connnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Pakrelible\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
                DataTable sdt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT brand,part_no,descrp,qty,unt_prc,total_prc FROM sale_temp ", connnn);
                sda.Fill(sdt);
                sale_grid.DataSource = sdt;
                connnn.Dispose();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Posting !", "Error");
                }
}
```